# How do I get an Ubuntu ISO that matches my Virtual Box image?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I’ve downloaded the Ubuntu Linux 12.04 x86 Vitual Box image and i got the ISO for the OS (as iso) from the Ubuntu site. But there looks to be a difference. The Ubuntu site downloads 12.04.2,

When I open my VM it asks if i want to install along side. That wasn’t what i expected, it feels like i have a miss matching VM and OS.

Is that likely?

Comment: Do you have an empty (blank) VM, or is there already an OS inside?

Comment: Yes. There is the 12.04 OS already there. I presume that because I get a dialog that ask me if I'd like to install the 12.04.2 along side the 12.04. However i don't see how to just use that 12.04 OS.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve? it looks like you have an already-installed VM, then are booting that VM pointing to an ISO image which then starts the Ubuntu installer, this is what asks you if you want to install that alongside your existing VM. This is expected behavior if you boot from an Ubuntu CD. If you don't want that, remove the ISO image, by clicking on the CD icon on the bottom right of the VirtualBox Window. Still, it would be good if you could clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Stepping way back, I'm trying to get into Clojure development and I thought I'd learn a bit about Linux as well.  The purpose here was to get an Ubuntu image setup up from Virtual Box. I thought you had to have an ISO mounted in order to start you VB image. I just tried what you said and it works. If you want to raise an answer I'll mark it as answered or I'll remove the question. It doesn't seem that helpful now.

Answer (score 0):

In short, 12.04 is a LTS release, 12.04.2 is the 2nd maintenance release or `service pack`.

As long as you run `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y` in the VM and wait for it to finish. You should be on 12.04.2 already, run `lsb_release -a` to confirm.

Using the 12.04.2 ISO is fine, there is no point to use 12.04 GA ISO.